# Using dictionary.get() in if condition

Tags: python

I'm currently building up an object from dictionaries with lots of optional key/value pairs. To handle the different cases i check if i need to add anything like:

```
if dict.get('someKey', None) is not None:
    obj.AddSomeKeyThingy(dict)
```

This seems to work but i wonder:

a) isn't the `is not None` redundant since the get returns either a value(which is guaranteed to be a non-empty string if the key is present) or None. So i should be able to scrap this part, right? Or

b) should i let the `is not None` stay where it is for readability -> maintainability?

(fyi: i'm not worried about a miniscule performance overhead here unless somebody makes a really good point about that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at some edge cases:

```
>>> bool({'someKey': None}.get('someKey') is not None)
False
>>> bool({'someKey': ''}['someKey'])
False
>>> bool({}['someKey'])
KeyError: 'someKey'
```

a) No it's not guaranteed. As shown above.
b) No, you should use something that actually works.

```
>>> 'someKey' in {'someKey': None}
True
>>> 'someKey' in {'someKey': ''}
True
>>> 'someKey' in {}
False
```

Comment: Regarding the edge cases: as i pointed out, the dictionary will contain non-empty empty string values, so things like `None` and `''` won't cause any trouble. However: thanks for the suggestion to use `in`, this is more readable and exhibits the behaviour i'm looking for.